# PowerShell Pester (Collections, Custom Objects, Complex Return Types)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-3.0, pester

Is there anyone who can provide me with some examples mentioned below within Pester how to archive this.

```
#Collections (Array, Hashtable, ArrayList, List of T)
#Custom objects (class xyz)
#Complex return types i.e. SQL Server System.Data.SqlClient.Datatable
```

Comment: Can you please give some example of what you have tried and where it is failing or not acting like you want?
Maybe try using something like Compare-Object - ```Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ObjectA.PsObject.Properties -DifferenceObject $ObjectB.PsObject.Properties | Should -Be $null```

Comment: I haven't tried nothing and I couldn't find any examples in the Pester documentation.

This is the reason that I posted a question to ask for some examples in Pester with Unit-Tests.

Comment: What you are asking is basically 6 different questions, how to write unit tests for 6 different data types. Simply Googling 'Powershell Pester **DataType**' is giving valid solutions within the first 3 or 4 results, try those solutions and if you are still struggling then ask here with your code that isn't working and we will help :)

Comment: Found a solution for my question.

Answer (score -4):

Resolved, I found a solution for this question.